# Widget failes to update after boot

Tags: android, widget

I'm trying to make a widget for a weather app but I'm facing some problems with it. It works fine when I place it on the home srceen but doesn't update/show data after reboot. My implementation is
 1.On the onUpdate I create and initialize the objects I need for the weather data and position

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;

    ForecastApi.create(Global.FORECAST_IO_API_KEY);
    initializeGoogleClient();

    WakeLocker.acquire(context);

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

2. On the onConnected method I call the request for the weather data

   @Override
   public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
   {

   ```
   SharedPreferences locationSettings =context.getSharedPreferences(Global.SAVED_LOCATION, 0); 
   boolean hasSavedLocation = locationSettings.getBoolean(Global.HAS_SAVED_LOCATION, false);
   List<Address> addresses = null;

   if (!hasSavedLocation)
   {
       mLocation = getLastLocation();
       addresses = LocationGetter.getLocationAddress(mLocation, context);
   }
   else
   {
       initializeSavedLocation(addresses);
   }

   SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(Global.SETTINGS, 0);

   /*
   if (ServicesChecker.isInternetAvailable())
   {
       getWeatherInfo(mLocation, addresses);
   }
   */
   getWeatherInfo(mLocation, addresses);
   ```

   }
3. On the success callback of the weather response I update the widget

   @Override
           public void success(WeatherResponse weatherResponse, Response response)
           {

   ```
           ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
           int[] allWidgetsIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

           for (int widgetId : allWidgetsIds)
           {

               //get weather response

               RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
               views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_icon, R.drawable.icon_cloudy);
               views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_temperature_text, UIUpdater.UpdateCurrentTemperature(weatherResponse.getCurrently(), context));

               Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

               PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

               views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_holder_widget, pendingIntent);
               //appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
               ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
               appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, views);
           }
           mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
           WakeLocker.release();
       }
   ```

Tried already to put the thread to sleep for few seconds thinking that it couldn't get the location or access the internet but didn't help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So silly. I've missed the most important part from the widget documentation. 
**Note**: Because AppWidgetProvider is an extension of BroadcastReceiver, your process is not guaranteed to keep running after the callback methods return (see BroadcastReceiver for information about the broadcast lifecycle). If your App Widget setup process can take several seconds (perhaps while performing web requests) and you require that your process continues, consider starting a Service in the onUpdate() method [App Widgets| Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html). After sending all the logic to a service everything run smoothly.